# How to send post vars in angularjs Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

How do I send POST variables to a REST api using a angularjs service?

Right now I have this:

```
angularjsServices.factory('LoginService', [ '$resource',
  function($resource){
    return function(user, pass){
      return $resource(baseURL + "/login", {}, {
        logIn: {method:'POST', params:{username: user, password: pass}, isArray:false}
      });
    }
  }]);
```

This way the variables are sent in the url.
(I'm using parts of [this tutorial](http://www.9bitstudios.com/2013/07/hmac-rest-api-security/) but it uses jQuery instead of angularJS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all don't mix your resource and service.

Declare only resource, like this:

```
resourceModule.factory('rsrUser', [ '$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource(baseURL + "/login", {}, {
        // removed params property, that set pre-bound parameters for this action
        logIn: {method:'POST', isArray:false}
    });
  }
]);
```

Then you can use this resource rsrUser in your service or controller:

```
controllerModule.controller('ctrlMain', [ '$scope', 'rsrUser',
  function($scope, rsrUser){
    // create resource instance and attach properties (which would become a POST body)
    $scope.user = new rsrUser
    $scope.user.username = 'savior'
    $scope.user.password = '123'

    // call resource action
    $scope.user.$logIn(function(){
      //success callback
    }, function() {
      //error callback
    })

  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use restangular https://github.com/mgonto/restangular

> AngularJS service to handle Rest API Restful Resources properly and
>   easily

To post you can do something like that

```
 var myBuilding = {
    name: "Gonto's Building",
    place: "Argentina"
  };

  // POST /accounts/123/buildings with MyBuilding information
  firstAccount.post("Buildings", myBuilding).then(function() {
    console.log("Object saved OK");
  }, function() {
    console.log("There was an error saving");
  });
```